# sankeyNetwork not recognizing customized colourScale

Tags: javascript, r, sankey-diagram, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I am creating a plot using sankeyNetwork in R and am having issues with the colourScale option. I created a custom color scale, and the plot that is produced is *so close* to being correct, but somewhere within the sankeyNetwork function, it's breaking and associating two groups with the wrong color.

Here is the color scale:

```
colorJS <- "d3.scaleOrdinal() .domain([\" Akatopora spp.\", \"brown fine bryozoan\", \"Bugula neritina\", \"Bugulina californica\", \"Calliarthron tuberculosum\", \"Cauloramphus echinus\", \"Cellaria mandibulata\", \"Celleporaria brunnea\", \"Ceramiales\", \"Cheilostomatida\", \"Chondracanthus spinosus\", \"Chondracanthus spp.\", \"Corallina officinalisvarchilensis\", \"Corallinales\", \"cream encrusting bryozoan\", \"Crisia occidentalis\", \"Cyclostomatida\", \"Diaperoforma californica\", \"Ectoprocta\", \"Gelidiales\", \"Gelidium robustum\", \"Gigartinales\", \"Gloiocladia laciniata\", \"Haywardipora spp.\", \"Jellyella white\", \"Lithothrix aspergillum\", \"Microcladia coulteri\", \"nongeniculate pink\", \"nongeniculate red\", \"other_algae\", \"Parasmittina tubulata\", \"peach encrusting bryozoan\", \"red_fil_alg\", \"red_turf_alg\", \"Rhodophyta\", \"Rhodymenia spp.\", \"Rhodymeniales\", \"Sarcodiotheca furcata\", \"Thalamoporella californica \"]) .range([\" #FF8C00\", \"#FF8C00\", \"#FF8C00\", \"#FF8C00\", \"#DB7093\", \"#FF8C00\", \"#FF8C00\", \"#FF8C00\", \"#DB7093\", \"#FF8C00\", \"#DB7093\", \"#DB7093\", \"#DB7093\", \"#DB7093\", \"#FF8C00\", \"#FF8C00\", \"#FF8C00\", \"#FF8C00\", \"#FF8C00\", \"#DB7093\", \"#DB7093\", \"#DB7093\", \"#DB7093\", \"#FF8C00\", \"#FF8C00\", \"#DB7093\", \"#DB7093\", \"#DB7093\", \"#DB7093\", \"#FFB90F\", \"#FF8C00\", \"#FF8C00\", \"#DB7093\", \"#DB7093\", \"#DB7093\", \"#DB7093\", \"#DB7093\", \"#DB7093\", \"#FF8C00 \"])"
```

Take note of the fact that "red_fil_alg" and "red_turf_alg" are associated with the pink color.

And here is the code for the sankeyNetwork:

```
sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "source", Target = "target",
              Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
              fontSize = 20, nodeWidth = 5,
              colourScale = colorJS,
              LinkGroup="group", NodeGroup = NULL)
```

Which produces this figure:
[image]

If it isn't obvious, the links between "other_algae" and "red_fil_alg" and "red_turf_alg" should be pink, not orange. I attempted to solve the problem by removing the spaces in the names of the nodes, but that didn't work. I checked to make sure the names of the nodes and the links match up using `setdiff()`.

Here are the links and the nodes, if they are useful:

```
> links
    source target     value           group
    1      18      9  1.000000      Ectoprocta
    2      18      9  1.500000      Ectoprocta
    3      18      9 15.900000      Ectoprocta
    4      18      9  1.000000      Ectoprocta
    5      18      9  1.000000      Ectoprocta
    6      18      9  1.363636      Ectoprocta
    7      18      9  1.357143      Ectoprocta
    8      18      9  3.025641      Ectoprocta
    9      18      9  3.333333      Ectoprocta
    10     18      9  1.666667      Ectoprocta
    11     18      9  4.934783      Ectoprocta
    12     18      9  4.500000      Ectoprocta
    13     18     16  1.125000      Ectoprocta
    14     18     16  1.250000      Ectoprocta
    15     18     16  2.818182      Ectoprocta
    16     34      8  1.000000      Rhodophyta
    17     34     13  1.000000      Rhodophyta
    18     34     13  8.333333      Rhodophyta
    19     34     13  1.000000      Rhodophyta
    20     34     13 24.655172      Rhodophyta
    21     34     13  8.243902      Rhodophyta
    22     34     19  1.000000      Rhodophyta
    23     34     21  2.000000      Rhodophyta
    24     34     21  3.000000      Rhodophyta
    25     34     21  2.000000      Rhodophyta
    26     34     29  2.555556      Rhodophyta
    27     34     29  5.921569      Rhodophyta
    28     34     36  1.769231      Rhodophyta
    29     34     36  4.187500      Rhodophyta
    30      9      0  1.000000 Cheilostomatida
    31      9      2  1.500000 Cheilostomatida
    32      9      3 15.900000 Cheilostomatida
    33      9      5  1.000000 Cheilostomatida
    34      9      6  1.000000 Cheilostomatida
    35      9      7  1.363636 Cheilostomatida
    36      9     14  1.357143 Cheilostomatida
    37      9     23  3.025641 Cheilostomatida
    38      9     24  3.333333 Cheilostomatida
    39      9     30  1.666667 Cheilostomatida
    40      9     31  4.934783 Cheilostomatida
    41      9     38  4.500000 Cheilostomatida
    42     16      1  1.125000  Cyclostomatida
    43     16     15  1.250000  Cyclostomatida
    44     16     17  2.818182  Cyclostomatida
    45      8     26  1.000000      Ceramiales
    46     13      4  1.000000    Corallinales
    47     13     12  8.333333    Corallinales
    48     13     25  1.000000    Corallinales
    49     13     27 24.655172    Corallinales
    50     13     28  8.243902    Corallinales
    51     19     20  1.000000      Gelidiales
    52     21     10  2.000000    Gigartinales
    53     21     11  3.000000    Gigartinales
    54     21     37  2.000000    Gigartinales
    55     29     32  2.555556     other_algae
    56     29     33  5.921569     other_algae
    57     36     22  1.769231   Rhodymeniales
    58     36     35  4.187500   Rhodymeniales

> nodes
                                name
1                     Akatopora spp.
2                brown fine bryozoan
3                    Bugula neritina
4               Bugulina californica
5          Calliarthron tuberculosum
6               Cauloramphus echinus
7               Cellaria mandibulata
8               Celleporaria brunnea
9                         Ceramiales
10                   Cheilostomatida
11           Chondracanthus spinosus
12               Chondracanthus spp.
13 Corallina officinalisvarchilensis
14                      Corallinales
15         cream encrusting bryozoan
16               Crisia occidentalis
17                    Cyclostomatida
18          Diaperoforma californica
19                        Ectoprocta
20                        Gelidiales
21                 Gelidium robustum
22                      Gigartinales
23             Gloiocladia laciniata
24                 Haywardipora spp.
25                   Jellyella white
26            Lithothrix aspergillum
27              Microcladia coulteri
28                nongeniculate pink
29                 nongeniculate red
30                       other_algae
31             Parasmittina tubulata
32         peach encrusting bryozoan
33                       red_fil_alg
34                      red_turf_alg
35                        Rhodophyta
36                   Rhodymenia spp.
37                     Rhodymeniales
38             Sarcodiotheca furcata
39        Thalamoporella californica
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested several changes to the code to narrow down the glitch (see below). None of them solve the problem, so the most likely cause is still a bug in the library, more specifically on how `sankeyNetwork()` runs through the ordinal scale of domains and ranges.
I suggest you flag this issue on the developer's space.
https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/issues?page=2&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen

As a matter of fact, there is a similar issue reported:
https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/issues/242
The solution to that one was removing spaces in the strings passed on to D3 as domain.
However, I have tried that one already without success:

- replaced spaces and underscores with "-"
- removed the dots after the "spp"s
- introduced a zero-based index in the nodes df to rule out this issue

```
    library(networkD3)
    library(tidyverse)
    nodes <- data.frame(names = c("Akatopora-spp","brown-fine-bryozoan","Bugula-neritina","Bugulina-californica","Calliarthron-tuberculosum","Cauloramphus-echinus","Cellaria-mandibulata","Celleporaria-brunnea","Ceramiales","Cheilostomatida","Chondracanthus-spinosus","Chondracanthus-spp","Corallina-officinalisvarchilensis","Corallinales","cream-encrusting-bryozoan","Crisia-occidentalis","Cyclostomatida","Diaperoforma-californica","Ectoprocta","Gelidiales","Gelidium-robustum","Gigartinales","Gloiocladia-laciniata","Haywardipora-spp","Jellyella-white","Lithothrix-aspergillum","Microcladia-coulteri","nongeniculate-pink","nongeniculate-red","Other-algae","Parasmittina-tubulata","peach-encrusting-bryozoan","red-fil-algae","red-turf-algae","Rhodophyta","Rhodymenia-spp","Rhodymeniales","Sarcodiotheca-furcata","Thalamoporella-californica"))
    
    links <- data.frame(matrix(c(1,18,9,1.000000,"Ectoprocta",2,18,9,1.500000,"Ectoprocta",3,18,9,15.900000,"Ectoprocta",4,18,9,1.000000,"Ectoprocta",5,18,9,1.000000,"Ectoprocta",6,18,9,1.363636,"Ectoprocta",7,18,9,1.357143,"Ectoprocta",8,18,9,3.025641,"Ectoprocta",9,18,9,3.333333,"Ectoprocta",10,18,9,1.666667,"Ectoprocta",11,18,9,4.934783,"Ectoprocta",12,18,9,4.500000,"Ectoprocta",13,18,16,1.125000,"Ectoprocta",14,18,16,1.250000,"Ectoprocta",15,18,16,2.818182,"Ectoprocta",16,34,8,1.000000,"Rhodophyta",17,34,13,1.000000,"Rhodophyta",18,34,13,8.333333,"Rhodophyta",19,34,13,1.000000,"Rhodophyta",20,34,13,24.655172,"Rhodophyta",21,34,13,8.243902,"Rhodophyta",22,34,19,1.000000,"Rhodophyta",23,34,21,2.000000,"Rhodophyta",24,34,21,3.000000,"Rhodophyta",25,34,21,2.000000,"Rhodophyta",26,34,29,2.555556,"Rhodophyta",27,34,29,5.921569,"Rhodophyta",28,34,36,1.769231,"Rhodophyta",29,34,36,4.187500,"Rhodophyta",30,9,0,1.000000,"Cheilostomatida",31,9,2,1.500000,"Cheilostomatida",32,9,3,15.900000,"Cheilostomatida",33,9,5,1.000000,"Cheilostomatida",34,9,6,1.000000,"Cheilostomatida",35,9,7,1.363636,"Cheilostomatida",36,9,14,1.357143,"Cheilostomatida",37,9,23,3.025641,"Cheilostomatida",38,9,24,3.333333,"Cheilostomatida",39,9,30,1.666667,"Cheilostomatida",40,9,31,4.934783,"Cheilostomatida",41,9,38,4.500000,"Cheilostomatida",42,16,1,1.125000,"Cyclostomatida",43,16,15,1.250000,"Cyclostomatida",44,16,17,2.818182,"Cyclostomatida",45,8,26,1.000000,"Ceramiales",46,13,4,1.000000,"Corallinales",47,13,12,8.333333,"Corallinales",48,13,25,1.000000,"Corallinales",49,13,27,24.655172,"Corallinales",50,13,28,8.243902,"Corallinales",51,19,20,1.000000,"Gelidiales",52,21,10,2.000000,"Gigartinales",53,21,11,3.000000,"Gigartinales",54,21,37,2.000000,"Gigartinales",55,29,32,2.555556,"other_algae",56,29,33,5.921569,"other_algae",57,36,22,1.769231,"Rhodymeniales",58,36,35,4.187500,"Rhodymeniales"), ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  rename(ID = X1, source = X2, target = X3, value = X4, group = X5) %>% 
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) # input links df
    links[links$group == "other-algae",]$group <- "Other-algae"
    
    nodes <- nodes %>% 
      rowid_to_column(., var = "ID") %>% # introduce index
      mutate(ID = ID-1) # zero-based index
    
    colorJS <- "d3.scaleOrdinal() .domain([\"Akatopora-spp\",\"brown-fine-bryozoan\",\"Bugula-neritina\",\"Bugulina-californica\",\"Calliarthron-tuberculosum\",\"Cauloramphus-echinus\",\"Cellaria-mandibulata\",\"Celleporaria-brunnea\",\"Ceramiales\",\"Cheilostomatida\",\"Chondracanthus-spinosus\",\"Chondracanthus-spp\",\"Corallina-officinalisvarchilensis\",\"Corallinales\",\"cream-encrusting-bryozoan\",\"Crisia-occidentalis\",\"Cyclostomatida\",\"Diaperoforma-californica\",\"Ectoprocta\",\"Gelidiales\",\"Gelidium-robustum\",\"Gigartinales\",\"Gloiocladia-laciniata\",\"Haywardipora-spp\",\"Jellyella-white\",\"Lithothrix-aspergillum\",\"Microcladia-coulteri\",\"nongeniculate-pink\",\"nongeniculate-red\",\"Other-algae\",\"Parasmittina-tubulata\",\"peach-encrusting-bryozoan\",\"red-fil-algae\",\"red-turf-algae\",\"Rhodophyta\",\"Rhodymenia-spp\",\"Rhodymeniales\",\"Sarcodiotheca-furcata\",\"Thalamoporella-californica\"]) .range([\" #FF8C00\",\"#FF8C00\",\"#FF8C00\",\"#FF8C00\",\"#DB7093\",\"#FF8C00\",\"#FF8C00\",\"#FF8C00\",\"#DB7093\",\"#FF8C00\",\"#DB7093\",\"#DB7093\",\"#DB7093\",\"#DB7093\",\"#FF8C00\",\"#FF8C00\",\"#FF8C00\",\"#FF8C00\",\"#FF8C00\",\"#DB7093\",\"#DB7093\",\"#DB7093\",\"#DB7093\",\"#FF8C00\",\"#FF8C00\",\"#DB7093\",\"#DB7093\",\"#DB7093\",\"#DB7093\",\"#FFB90F\",\"#FF8C00\",\"#FF8C00\",\"#DB7093\",\"#DB7093\",\"#DB7093\",\"#DB7093\",\"#DB7093\",\"#DB7093\",\"#FF8C00\"])"
    
    sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
                  Source = "source", Target = "target",
                  Value = "value", NodeID = "names",
                  fontSize = 20, nodeWidth = 5, 
                  colourScale = colorJS,
                  LinkGroup="group", NodeGroup = NULL)
```

Output:
[image: sankeyNetwork plot with new strings]

Oddly enough, the links in question turn out dark orange -same as the top category- and not light orange as in your original output:
[image: original plot with two different levels of orange]

I also tried a standard D3 colour scale `colourScale = JS("d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20)")` and it seems to run fine through your original node categories:
[image: standard D3 ordinal colour scale]

Furthermore, the node-link structure seems to be correct, as seen when building a simple network (the problematic nodes are highlighted):

```
    simpleNetwork(links, Source = "source",
              Target = "target",
              fontSize = 14,
              fontFamily = "serif",
              linkColour = "#666",
              nodeColour = "#69b3a2",
              opacity = 0.9,
              zoom = T)
```

[image: network structure]

Finally I tried to run the domain through a three-colour scale to watch the behaviour. The "Ceramiales" category is assigned the same colour as "Other-algae" so the issue is not directly related to the string in the problematic category.

```
    colorJS2 <- "d3.scaleOrdinal() .domain([\"Akatopora spp.\", \"brown fine bryozoan\", \"Bugula neritina\", \"Bugulina californica\", \"Calliarthron tuberculosum\", \"Cauloramphus echinus\", \"Cellaria mandibulata\", \"Celleporaria brunnea\", \"Ceramiales\", \"Cheilostomatida\", \"Chondracanthus spinosus\", \"Chondracanthus spp.\", \"Corallina officinalisvarchilensis\", \"Corallinales\", \"cream encrusting bryozoan\", \"Crisia occidentalis\", \"Cyclostomatida\", \"Diaperoforma californica\", \"Ectoprocta\", \"Gelidiales\", \"Gelidium robustum\", \"Gigartinales\", \"Gloiocladia laciniata\", \"Haywardipora spp.\", \"Jellyella white\", \"Lithothrix aspergillum\", \"Microcladia coulteri\", \"nongeniculate pink\", \"nongeniculate red\", \"other_algae\", \"Parasmittina tubulata\", \"peach encrusting bryozoan\", \"red_fil_alg\", \"red_turf_alg\", \"Rhodophyta\", \"Rhodymenia spp.\", \"Rhodymeniales\", \"Sarcodiotheca furcata\", \"Thalamoporella californica\"]) .range([\" #222222\", \"#DB7093\", \"#FFB90F\"])"

    sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "source", Target = "target",
              Value = "value", NodeID = "names",
              fontSize = 20, nodeWidth = 5,
              colourScale = colorJS2,
              LinkGroup="group", NodeGroup = NULL)
```

Output:
[image: three-colour loop]

Hence my guess about a glitch in the way the function runs through the js domain and range strings.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There's a mistake in your list of colors. You're explicitly setting the color for "other_algae" to "#FFB90F". If you fix that, it will have the right color...

```r
links <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
source target     value           group
18      9  1.000000      Ectoprocta
18      9  1.500000      Ectoprocta
18      9 15.900000      Ectoprocta
18      9  1.000000      Ectoprocta
18      9  1.000000      Ectoprocta
18      9  1.363636      Ectoprocta
18      9  1.357143      Ectoprocta
18      9  3.025641      Ectoprocta
18      9  3.333333      Ectoprocta
18      9  1.666667      Ectoprocta
18      9  4.934783      Ectoprocta
18      9  4.500000      Ectoprocta
18     16  1.125000      Ectoprocta
18     16  1.250000      Ectoprocta
18     16  2.818182      Ectoprocta
34      8  1.000000      Rhodophyta
34     13  1.000000      Rhodophyta
34     13  8.333333      Rhodophyta
34     13  1.000000      Rhodophyta
34     13 24.655172      Rhodophyta
34     13  8.243902      Rhodophyta
34     19  1.000000      Rhodophyta
34     21  2.000000      Rhodophyta
34     21  3.000000      Rhodophyta
34     21  2.000000      Rhodophyta
34     29  2.555556      Rhodophyta
34     29  5.921569      Rhodophyta
34     36  1.769231      Rhodophyta
34     36  4.187500      Rhodophyta
9      0  1.000000 Cheilostomatida
9      2  1.500000 Cheilostomatida
9      3 15.900000 Cheilostomatida
9      5  1.000000 Cheilostomatida
9      6  1.000000 Cheilostomatida
9      7  1.363636 Cheilostomatida
9     14  1.357143 Cheilostomatida
9     23  3.025641 Cheilostomatida
9     24  3.333333 Cheilostomatida
9     30  1.666667 Cheilostomatida
9     31  4.934783 Cheilostomatida
9     38  4.500000 Cheilostomatida
16      1  1.125000  Cyclostomatida
16     15  1.250000  Cyclostomatida
16     17  2.818182  Cyclostomatida
 8     26  1.000000      Ceramiales
13      4  1.000000    Corallinales
13     12  8.333333    Corallinales
13     25  1.000000    Corallinales
13     27 24.655172    Corallinales
13     28  8.243902    Corallinales
19     20  1.000000      Gelidiales
21     10  2.000000    Gigartinales
21     11  3.000000    Gigartinales
21     37  2.000000    Gigartinales
29     32  2.555556     other_algae
29     33  5.921569     other_algae
36     22  1.769231   Rhodymeniales
36     35  4.187500   Rhodymeniales
")



nodes <- read.csv(header = TRUE, text ="
name
Akatopora spp.
brown fine bryozoan
Bugula neritina
Bugulina californica
Calliarthron tuberculosum
Cauloramphus echinus
Cellaria mandibulata
Celleporaria brunnea
Ceramiales
Cheilostomatida
Chondracanthus spinosus
Chondracanthus spp.
Corallina officinalisvarchilensis
Corallinales
cream encrusting bryozoan
Crisia occidentalis
Cyclostomatida
Diaperoforma californica
Ectoprocta
Gelidiales
Gelidium robustum
Gigartinales
Gloiocladia laciniata
Haywardipora spp.
Jellyella white
Lithothrix aspergillum
Microcladia coulteri
nongeniculate pink
nongeniculate red
other_algae
Parasmittina tubulata
peach encrusting bryozoan
red_fil_alg
red_turf_alg
Rhodophyta
Rhodymenia spp.
Rhodymeniales
Sarcodiotheca furcata
Thalamoporella californica
")

colors <- read.csv(header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE, text = "
domain                              ,  range
Akatopora spp.                      ,  #FF8C00
brown fine bryozoan                 ,  #FF8C00
Bugula neritina                     ,  #FF8C00
Bugulina californica                ,  #FF8C00
Calliarthron tuberculosum           ,  #DB7093
Cauloramphus echinus                ,  #FF8C00
Cellaria mandibulata                ,  #FF8C00
Celleporaria brunnea                ,  #FF8C00
Ceramiales                          ,  #DB7093
Cheilostomatida                     ,  #FF8C00
Chondracanthus spinosus             ,  #DB7093
Chondracanthus spp.                 ,  #DB7093
Corallina officinalisvarchilensis   ,  #DB7093
Corallinales                        ,  #DB7093
cream encrusting bryozoan           ,  #FF8C00
Crisia occidentalis                 ,  #FF8C00
Cyclostomatida                      ,  #FF8C00
Diaperoforma californica            ,  #FF8C00
Ectoprocta                          ,  #FF8C00
Gelidiales                          ,  #DB7093
Gelidium robustum                   ,  #DB7093
Gigartinales                        ,  #DB7093
Gloiocladia laciniata               ,  #DB7093
Haywardipora spp.                   ,  #FF8C00
Jellyella white                     ,  #FF8C00
Lithothrix aspergillum              ,  #DB7093
Microcladia coulteri                ,  #DB7093
nongeniculate pink                  ,  #DB7093
nongeniculate red                   ,  #DB7093
other_algae                         ,  #DB7093
Parasmittina tubulata               ,  #FF8C00
peach encrusting bryozoan           ,  #FF8C00
red_fil_alg                         ,  #DB7093
red_turf_alg                        ,  #DB7093
Rhodophyta                          ,  #DB7093
Rhodymenia spp.                     ,  #DB7093
Rhodymeniales                       ,  #DB7093
Sarcodiotheca furcata               ,  #DB7093
Thalamoporella californica          ,  #FF8C00
")


library(networkD3)

colorJS <- paste0("d3.scaleOrdinal().domain([\"", paste(colors$domain, collapse = "\", \""), "\"]).range([\"", paste(colors$range, collapse = "\", \""), "\"])")

sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "source", Target = "target",
              Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
              fontSize = 20, nodeWidth = 5,
              colourScale = colorJS,
              LinkGroup="group", NodeGroup = NULL)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. Replacing all white spaces in the node names through non-breaking white spaces solved the problem.